Where are the install instructions for CiviCRM with Drupal 11?
There have been postings in various places since July, 2024 applauding how CiviCRM will be compatible with Drupal 11 from the day that Drupal 11 becomes available.
I have a working Drupal 11 web site, but when I tried to install CiviCRM via composer, the install fails every time.
I am assuming that I am simply "doing it wrong" somehow, so this question is mostly just asking for a URL where installation instructions can be found.
Thank you!

The quick answer is the instructions for civi+11 are the same as 10 you just need to be using a high enough version of civi (5.75).
But there are lots of reasons any install can fail. It's better if you give the specific error message. My guess is maybe you have some non-stock module installed that uses a library that conflicts with civi's constraints.

As soon as I try the install again, I'll provide far more detail.  But for what it is worth, the only module I installed was the one that allows Drupal 11 to run with the MariaDB version that works on Debian 10.  Could that be the issue?
